# Can a filesystem be encrypted in such a way that only specific processes can access it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, root, disk-encryption

I can certainly mount a filesystem and all the files in it as `700`, but I want something even tighter than that. Let's say someone manages to get into my system, somehow. They'd be able to read just about anything, anywhere, including... say... a configuration file with IDs and secrets in it. Maybe they'd be able to find an `id_rsa` or private user data.

If there's a way that a process could access a filesystem only if it authenticated with the kernel, or held a crypto key, or spoke the magic word, then any other incarnation of root - even if someone got my process to `exec` `bash` - would be unable to see any of the secrets that would elevate their access.

Does linux provide a way to accomplish this? I don't know how much room we have to move potentially sensitive files, but I should be able to replace them with links across to the encrypted filesystem.

Comment: Not encryption, but research "mandatory access control". SELinux and AppArmor are the canonical examples in the Linux world.

Comment: @berndbausch would MAC be sufficient to distinguish between multiple logins of the same user? Wouldn’t that involve some sort of ABAC?

Comment: MAC is probably not what OP wants, since they mention some authentication with the kernel or a key that the process has to prove that they have the right to access resources. I don't know to what level of detail SELinux (as an example) can go. Not sure if the question is precise enough right now for a reasonable answer.

Comment: Did you consider posting this question over at [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @AdminBee: I didn't know about that one. I've been active here and on superuser, but that's about it - this isn't a space I spend a lot of time in. =]